# Pointer objects, cant break out of input loop

Tags: c++, class, loops, pointers, object

My program reads input from the user and sets a target and then reads more input from the user. It then compares the numbers entered after the target is initialized and incriments greater_than, less_than, and equal. I am confused on why my program will not break out of the loop when I enter the 'ctrl+d' command for no more input. This is a representative example of a test question for my midterm so I am not allowed to change main(); or in list.h and no I am not violating any of my teachers cheating policies because I am not turning in this work I am using solutions given as means of study.

Here is my code thank you in advance.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "list.h"

int main()
{
    List list;
    int value;
    int target;

    // first number read is the target
    cin >> target;

    while (cin >> value)
    {
      list.insert(value);
    }

    // initialized to 100 to make sure List::compare() initializes them correctly
    int less_than = 100;
    int equal = 100;
    int greater_than = 100;
    list.compare(target, less_than, equal, greater_than);

    cout << "target = " << target << endl;
    cout << "less_than = " << less_than << endl;
    cout << "equal = " << equal << endl;
    cout << "greater_than = " << greater_than << endl;
}
```

list.h

// Linked-List of Integers

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

class List
{
    public:
        List();
        ~List();
        void insert(int value); // insert at beginning of list
        void print(); // print all values in the list
        void compare(int target, int &less_than, int &equal, int &greater_than);

    private:
        class Node
        {
            public:
                Node(int value, Node *next)
                {m_value = value; m_next = next;}
                int m_value;
                Node *m_next;
        };
        Node *m_front;
};

#endif
```

list.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "list.h"

List::List()
{
    m_front = NULL;
}

// delete all Nodes in the list
// since they are dynamically allocated using new, they won't go away
// automatically when the list is deleted
// Rule of thumb: destructor deletes all memory created by member functions
List::~List()
{
    while (m_front)
    {
        Node *tmp = m_front;
        m_front = m_front->m_next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}

// always insert at the front of the list
// Note: this works even in the SPECIAL CASE that the list is empty
void List::insert(int value)
{
    m_front = new Node(value, m_front);
}

// iterate through all the Nodes in the list and print each Node
void List::print()
{
    for (Node *ptr = m_front; ptr; ptr = ptr->m_next)
    {
        cout << ptr->m_value << endl; 
    }
}

void List::compare(int target, int &less_than, int &equal, int &greater_than)
{

  less_than = 0;
  equal = 0;
  greater_than = 0;
  int targ;
  targ = target;


  Node *ptr = m_front;
  while(ptr != NULL){

if(ptr ->m_value == targ){

  equal++;
}
else if (ptr -> m_value > targ){

  greater_than++;
}
else if (ptr -> m_value <targ){
  less_than++;
}
  }
  ptr = ptr -> m_next;
}
```

Comment: And when you executed your code in a debugger, one line at a time, what observations did you make in the debugger, as to why your code "will not break out of the loop"?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  CTRL-D is EOF on Linux - but on Windows you need CTRL-Z + ENTER.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it actually gave me a segmentation fault on line 66 not sure why Im getting that. Im still very bad at pointers and I could be missing something trivial.

Comment: @Martin Bonner I am using windows 10 OS and I am using a vim editor. I still have much to learn about mastering it.

Comment: Well, nobody is going to count lines in the shown code to figure out which one is the 66th line. Furthermore, a segmentation fault is typically due to a bad pointer. So, at the point where a segfault occurs, examining the pointer will identify the reason for the segfault, by backtracking from that point on and figuring out how the pointer ended up being bad. If necessary, by repeatedly setting a breakpoint at a progressively earlier point, and examining the program's data in question in order to establish the sequence of steps that resulted in a bad pointer. This is called "debugging".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Im sorry I forgot stack does not display the numbers. The error at the end of list.cpp.             "ptr = ptr -> m_next;"           Im not sure how it is a bad pointer. Pointers are already hard for me to understand.

Comment: Are we talking about the function `compare`: Please [edit] the question to format that correctly too.    (Also, be consistent about spacing around `->`.  Personally I would always use *no* spaces.

Comment: You need to start by reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.  It may be helpful to enter just two items in your list.

Comment: Also, you have a destructor.  That means you need to do something about copy construction and assignment.  Add `List(const List&) = delete;` and `List& operator =(const List&) = delete;` to your List class.  (This disables copy construction and assignment, and will be good enough for the moment.)